# Silverstripe date and image error

Tags: silverstripe

This is the .ss template file:

```
<ul>
    <% control Menu(1) %>
    <li><a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a></li>
    <% end_control %>
</ul>
<div>
    <h1>$Title</h1>
    <div>Date : $Date.nice</div>

    $layout
    $Content
</div>
```

This is the php file:

```
class ArticlePage extends Page { 

    static $db = array( 
        'Date' => 'Date', 
    ); 

    private static $has_one = array( 
        'SingleImage' => 'Image'
    ); 

    function getCMSFields() { 
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields(); 

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content.Main', new DateField('Date'), 'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Upload',  
            $uploadField = new UploadField(
                $name = 'SingleImage',
                $title = 'Upload a single image', "Content"));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

The date and image are not showing up on the page.

Comment: Can you share the `$db` and `$has_one` variables from your class please? Are the items saving in CMS? Do the image and date value appear when the page is reloaded in the CMS after saving?

Comment: I don't see any code in your ss template for the image `$SingleImage`. Is it in your layout ss template file? Or is it missing?

Comment: <?php
class ArticlePage extends Page { // Model
    static $db = array(
       'Date' => 'Date',
    );
   private static $has_one = array(
        'SingleImage' => 'Image'
    );
    function getCMSFields() {
       $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    
  this is the php file and ss file i am editing plz help me with the code.

Comment: In future, please edit your question and add those details in, if they are helpful to understanding your question. Do not paste that in a comment. I have done it for you this time around. Can you answer my other questions about the items saving in the CMS and the missing `$SingleImage` in your template?

Comment: I dont knw the code i am new with silverstripe....

Comment: Are you using Silverstripe 3.1 or 2.4? You seem to have bits of code from both. For example `control` is from 2.4 and 3.0. This is replaced with `loop` in 3.1. `private static $has_one` is 3.1 code. 'Root.Content.Main' is 2.4 code. `UploadField` is 3.0 / 3.1 code. I would be surprised if the CMS worked without any errors in any version.

Comment: Welcome to Silverstripe and StackOverflow. My recommendation would be to learn the basics first. Go through the [Silverstripe tutorials](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/), especially [tutorial 1](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/1-building-a-basic-site) and [tutorial 2](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/2-extending-a-basic-site). Looking at your question, it looks like you might be trying tutorial 2. Go through it making sure you get all the details correct. When getting code from other places, make sure they are for the same SS version.

Answer (score 0):

This could be any number of things.

It could be that you have not set the page type properly in the CMS.

It could be that you have not flushed your template cache. 
To do this append `?flush=all` to the end of your URL.

It could be that you have not done either of the above and have not completed a database build yet either. 
To do this visit `yoursite/dev/build`.

It could be that you have not named the template correctly. It must mirror the php Class name (ArticlePage.ss)

It could be that you have not put this in the correct place. It must be in a templates folder in either the selected theme or your project folder. A flush is required after relocating the file (see above).

If you are using a theme it could be that you do not have the correct theme selected. See the documentation on this.

It could be because you're not being diligent with your code. The dot method for formatting a date nicely is `.Nice`, not `.nice`. `$Date.asdf` would also cause nothing to show up - as you are describing. Template variables fail silently if there is no sensible value to output.

Similar to the above - the layout variable is `$Layout`, not `$layout` (although this is irrelevant to this particular problem). `$Layout` also only works in 'main' templates (in the base 'templates' folder, not in the 'Layout' subfolder).

If all of the above checks out, then it could be simply that you have not put any information in through the CMS yet. You must of course complete this step before anything will show up.